# Excel VBA copy Text Box (Text and Format) to another Text Box (no ActiveX / User Forms)

Tags: excel, vba, duplicates, textbox, format

I am trying to copy the contents (text and format) from a text box on one sheet to another text box on another sheet within the same workbook. I have been able to successfully copy over almost everything, but the justification (center/left/right) is not working for each individual line. I am doing this in a very clunky way: copy the text, then loop through each character to get the format set. There does not seem to be an easy way in excel vba to copy both the text and ALL of the format over. Essentially I am trying to do a "select all (Cntrl-A)", "copy (Cnrl-C)" on the origin textbox, then do a "paste special (keep source formatting)" on the destination text box.  IT works wonderfully using the mouse, but I do not want to do that.  I just want to run a macro to do the same thing. Also, I noted that when the macro runs, the destination text box applies justification global to the text and I am no longer able to individually select a single line and set its justification (i.e. either all lines are centered or all lines are left justified vs. being able to adjust each line individually). Again, this weird behavior only happens after the macro is run.  If I use the mouse cut-and-paste method, the text is able to be justified line-by-line again. Here is my clunky code:

```
Sub Update_CARD_LEG_BACK()
    ' Set varibles to reduce typing and make changing origin and destination text boxes easier.
    Set Orig = Sheets("MAIN_INPUT2").Shapes("CARD_LEG_BACK")
    Set Orig_Sheet = Sheets("MAIN_INPUT2")
    Set Dest = Sheets("CARD_LEGACY").Shapes("BACK")
    Set Dest_Sheet = Sheets("CARD_LEGACY")

    'Copy text from origin text box to destination text box.  Copies only the text NO formating.
    Dest.TextFrame.Characters.Text = Orig.TextFrame.Characters.Text

    For i = 1 To Len(Orig.TextFrame.Characters.Text)
        Dest.TextFrame.Characters(i, 1).Font.Underline = Orig.TextFrame.Characters(i, 1).Font.Underline
        With Dest.TextFrame2.TextRange.Characters(i, 1)
            .Text = Orig.TextFrame2.TextRange.Characters(i, 1).Text
        With .Font
            .Name = Orig.TextFrame2.TextRange.Characters(i, 1).Font.Name
            .Size = Orig.TextFrame2.TextRange.Characters(i, 1).Font.Size
            .Bold = Orig.TextFrame2.TextRange.Characters(i, 1).Font.Bold
            .Strikethrough = Orig.TextFrame2.TextRange.Characters(i, 1).Font.Strikethrough
            .Superscript = Orig.TextFrame2.TextRange.Characters(i, 1).Font.Superscript
            .Subscript = Orig.TextFrame2.TextRange.Characters(i, 1).Font.Subscript
            .Fill.ForeColor.RGB = Orig.TextFrame2.TextRange.Characters(i, 1).Font.Fill.ForeColor.RGB
            .Fill.BackColor.RGB = Orig.TextFrame2.TextRange.Characters(i, 1).Font.Fill.BackColor.RGB
            .Fill.Visible = Orig.TextFrame2.TextRange.Characters(i, 1).Font.Fill.Visible
            .Fill.Transparency = Orig.TextFrame2.TextRange.Characters(i, 1).Font.Fill.Transparency
        End With
        With .ParagraphFormat
           .BaselineAlignment = Orig.TextFrame2.TextRange.Characters(i, 1).ParagraphFormat.BaselineAlignment
           .SpaceWithin = Orig.TextFrame2.TextRange.Characters(i, 1).ParagraphFormat.SpaceWithin
           .SpaceBefore = Orig.TextFrame2.TextRange.Characters(i, 1).ParagraphFormat.SpaceBefore
           .SpaceAfter = Orig.TextFrame2.TextRange.Characters(i, 1).ParagraphFormat.SpaceAfter
           .IndentLevel = Orig.TextFrame2.TextRange.Characters(i, 1).ParagraphFormat.IndentLevel
           .FirstLineIndent = Orig.TextFrame2.TextRange.Characters(i, 1).ParagraphFormat.FirstLineIndent
           .Alignment = Orig.TextFrame2.TextRange.Characters(i, 1).ParagraphFormat.Alignment
           .HangingPunctuation = Orig.TextFrame2.TextRange.Characters(i, 1).ParagraphFormat.HangingPunctuation
         End With
       End With
    Next i

    'Copy fill color of origin text box to destination text box. Also copies transparancy (required for 'no fill' option to copy correctly).
    Dest.Fill.ForeColor.RGB = Orig.Fill.ForeColor.RGB
    Dest.Fill.Transparency = Orig.Fill.Transparency
End Sub
```

Comment: Have you considered deleting the second text box and replacing it with a copy of the first one?  Seems that might be easier than replicating so many properties from the first one...

Comment: Trying it now.  I just need to be able to position the Pasted text box in the correct position on the destination page.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could replace the second with a copy of the first:

```vb
Sub Tester()

    ReplaceWithCopy Sheet1.Shapes("SourceTB"), Sheet2.Shapes("DestTB")

End Sub


Sub ReplaceWithCopy(shpSrc As Shape, shpDest As Shape)
    Dim nm As String
    
    shpSrc.Copy
    shpDest.Parent.Paste
    With shpDest.Parent.Shapes(shpDest.Parent.Shapes.Count)
        .Left = shpDest.Left
        .Top = shpDest.Top
        .Width = shpDest.Width
        .Height = shpDest.Height
        nm = shpDest.Name
        shpDest.Delete   'remove the shape being replaced
        .Name = nm       'rename copy to just-deleted shape
    End With
End Sub
```

Comment: Brilliant!!  Exactly what I was looking for, thanks so much!

Comment: I am having some difficultly now.  For some reason it works with certain text boxes, but for others it does not work. Any ideas why?  It copies the Src text box and deletes the Dest text box, but it will not rename or move the newly copied text box.  It appears perhaps it is not referencing the correct text box with the 'shpDest.Parent.Shapes.Count' variable.  I don't understand why it would not always work.

Comment: It worked for me in testing with one pair of textboxes. Do you have grouped or nested shapes?  Do you get any error message when it doesn't work?

Comment: yes, I have many grouped text boxes, and there are no error msgs. Everything works, except the moving and renaming, which tells me the 'Shapes(shpDest.Parent.Shapes.Count)' is not latching onto the correct shape. Since I copy the shape, the name of the newly copied shape is the same as the Src.  Can we just use that name instead of the count?

Comment: You can, but also be aware that there's nothing stopping you from naming two shapes on a sheet with the same name, which can cause problems when trying to access a shape later using its name.

Comment: How do I do that.  I know it must be something like: shpDest.Parent.shpSrc, but this is wrong.  I just want the Shape("<name>") from the shpSrc variable.

Comment: `shpDest.Parent.Shapes(shpSrc.Name)`

Comment: thanks again!  That works great.  Since I have no repeat textbox names, this should not be a problem.  Any ideas why the original code would not reference the correct shape?

Comment: I can't really say without an example of your workbook setup: I only tested with a very simple example.